# Enter Event to move to another textbox

Tags: c#

how I can move cursor  from textbox to another when I press Enter key.

I know how to do that by tab key.

I wish if someone help me.

Comment: Windows Forms ? WPF ? ASP.NET ? Other ? Please be more precise.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to move to specific TextBox try this:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        textBox2.Focus();
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Override the containing form's ProcessDialogKey ()

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
            e.Handled = true;
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        }
    }
```

If you want the Enter to always behave as TAB, you can set the `KeyPreview` property on the form to `true` and do it in the Form.KeyDown event instead. For some controls, it still works the standard way (if a button has the focus, the button is pressed when hitting Enter, and TAB is **not** executed...)

```
    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
            e.Handled = true;
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        }
    }
```

Note: This works for Windows Forms. If other technology, please specify in original question by tag or as text in question.

Comment: can't we do it without using postback in asp.net?

Comment: @KrishnaThota: As I said in my answer: This is for Windows Forms. If used in web, you need to use client-side javascript. I'm not sure how to do it, though. You might post a separate question where you ask this.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `Tabindex` property. It can be set from the Properties window of the control so if Tabindex is 2, then the tab key has to be pressed 2 times to reach that control.

For enter, do the defaultvalue & set it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply simulate the TAB key
There is a .NET class who let's you SendKeys to a control
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send(...